# jQuery conditional problem

Tags: jquery, css, conditional-statements, height

I am trying to create a conditional statement on my dynamic product pages on my website, to aid the setting of the height of my columns (both left and right) and the center part (the `#detail <div>`).

I have this bit of code now:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  detailHeight = $('#detail').height();
  columnHeight = detailHeight + 20;

  $('.columns').height(columnHeight);
  $('#detail').height(columnHeight);

});
```

Now, I want to make sure that the height of the `columnHeight` variable is at least 550, so that the height of the columns and the `#detail <div>` will be at least 550px tall.

This is due to my Mario artwork with him placing a call on the right-hand column.  It looks a little unprofessional if it overhangs into the footer.

I'm trying to add a conditional:

```
if($(columnHeight) < 550) {
    columnHeight = 550;
}
```

To my previous code like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  detailHeight = $('#detail').height();
  columnHeight = detailHeight + 20;

  if($(columnHeight) < 550) {
      columnHeight = 550;
  }

  $('.columns').height(columnHeight);
  $('#detail').height(columnHeight);

});
```

For some reason, it loads the same as if the conditional weren't even there.

You can view the effects of the problem here at:

http://www.marioplanet.com/catalog.asp and clicking through to any of the products,

or,

by going to http://www.marioplanet.com/product.asp?IDnum=1 and by changing the number in the `IDnum=1` in the last part of the URL to anything in between 1 and 45.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to everyone who posted!

Wow, what a lame mistake!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to include the `$` in front of columnHeight?

```
if($(columnHeight) < 550) {
    columnHeight = 550;
}
```

should be:

```
if(columnHeight < 550) {
    columnHeight = 550;
}
```

You are wrapping a number into a jQuery object. I actually have no idea of what this would be expected to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(columnHeight < 550) {
     columnHeight = 550;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're jQuery-fying the `columnHeight`. Give this a shot:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  detailHeight = $('#detail').height();
  columnHeight = detailHeight + 20;

  if(columnHeight < 550) {
      columnHeight = 550;
  }

  $('.columns').height(columnHeight);
  $('#detail').height(columnHeight);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be...

```
if(columnHeight < 550) {
    columnHeight = 550;  
}
```

...as your example is trying to create a jQuery object from a simple variable?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the CSS min-height property on .columns and #detail?

```
.columns, #detail {
    min-height: 550px;
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot, thanks!  I've never heard of this before, and it's quite useful here.  I'm looking for jQuery code in this instance, though so yeah.  But I may actually implement this instead.

Comment: @BOSS - there are actually 100% CSS ways to create your column layout; no JavaScript needed. Ex.: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths